# Ramification index of an ideal vs. ramification index of a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, riemannian-geometry

I am familiar with two uses of the term "Ramification index": 1. The ramification index in the context of algebraic number fields, i.e. the exponent of a prime ideal in the decomposition of a prime ideal it lies over, and 
2. The ramification index in the context of Riemann surfaces and algebraic curves, spacifically in the context of the  Riemann-Hurwitz formula. Is there a connection between the two?

Comment: Yes, it's just the same. On affine pieces a morphism of curves corresponds to a map of the rings of regular functions in the other direction, and these are Dedekind domains. Points correspond to maximal ideals.

Comment: Do you have a reference were I could read more on the subject?

Comment: Fulton's book is a delightful intro, and you can jump in where you need to depending on how familiar you are already with the basics: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf The relevant stuff is in Chapter 8.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20190523194659/http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf looks to be the last cache entry